# How to perform a trend test

Tags: generalized-linear-model, survey, trend

I'm working on a glm model (family:normal, link:identity) using complex survey design (package: survey), My interest is to evaluate the effect of the variable DLA on the scores.

I ran the model 1 considering DLA as categorical (tertiles):

```r
model1 = svyglm(score ~ DLA_tert + race + pir_4 + age_yr + 
           as.factor(educa), design1[age_yr>69], 
           data=base_sex2[age_yr>69])
```

Here are the results for this model

```r
    Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)          90.6470    13.4223   6.753 6.49e-06 ***
    DLA_tert(37.1,63.1]  -1.5940     1.9428  -0.820 0.424793    
    DLA_tert(63.1,507]   -3.1713     2.2090  -1.436 0.171632    
    race2               -12.6004     2.4078  -5.233 0.000101 ***
    race3                -9.1128     2.5326  -3.598 0.002635 ** 
    race4               -10.3232     2.4077  -4.288 0.000648 ***
    pir_42                2.7497     2.5701   1.070 0.301593    
    pir_43                6.8206     2.6690   2.555 0.021959 *  
    pir_44                6.3329     3.2067   1.975 0.066985 .  
    age_yr               -0.8075     0.1779  -4.539 0.000392 ***
    as.factor(educa)2     8.3018     2.3218   3.576 0.002760 ** 
    as.factor(educa)3    13.5644     2.0637   6.573 8.84e-06 ***
    as.factor(educa)4    15.3992     2.2397   6.876 5.27e-06 ***
    as.factor(educa)5    17.9402     2.7926   6.424 1.14e-05 ***
```

I suspect there is a trend in the association between my tertiles and scores (even if the association is not significant).
I would like to know how to calculate this trend and the p-value for it?

Comment: How would you answer the same question in a linear regression without complex survey design?

Comment: I really don't know. I would maybe introduce the variable of interest as integer, and see how my association is?

Comment: That's a good idea. Is it important to categorize DLA from a scientific point of view?

Comment: Yes, the idea was to detect any dose-response relationship or any point of inflexion

Comment: Then I do not understand why you categorize DLA. It throws away key info about your questions, especially concerning the inflection point.